# Matlab solving ODE applied to State Space System, inputs time dependent

Tags: matlab, state, space, ode

I've got at State System, with "forced" inputs at bounds. My SS equation is: zp = A*z * B. (A is a square matrix, and B colunm)

If B is a step (along the time of experience), there is no problem, because I can use

```
  tevent = 2;
  tmax= 5*tevent;

  n =100;
  dT = n/tmax;
  t = linspace(0,tmax,n);
  u0 = 1 * ones(size(z'));
  B = zeros(nz,n);
  B(1,1)= utop(1)';
  A = eye(nz,nz);

  [tt,u]=ode23('SS',t,u0);
```

and SS is:

```
  function zp = SS(t,z)
          global A B
          zp = A*z + B;
  end
```

My problem is when I applied a slop, So B will be time dependent.

```
  utop_init= 20;
  utop_final = 50;
  utop(1)=utop_init;
  utop(tevent * dT)=utop_final;

  for k = 2: tevent*dT -1
      utop(k) = utop(k-1) +(( utop(tevent * dT) - utop(1))/(tevent * dT));
  end

  for k = (tevent * dT) +1 :(tmax*dT)
      utop(k) = utop(k-1);
  end

  global A B
  B = zeros(nz,1);
  B(1,1:n) = utop(:)';
  A = eye(nz,nz);
```

I wrote a new equation (to trying to solve), the problem, but I can't adjust "time step", and I don't get a u with 22x100 (which is the objective).

```
  for k = 2 : n
  u=solveSS(t,k,u0);
  end
```

SolveSS has the code:

```
function [ u ] = solveSS( t,k,u0)

  tspan = [t(k-1) t(k)];

  [t,u] = ode15s(@SS,tspan,u0);

      function zp = SS(t,z)
          global A B
          zp = A*z + B(:,k-1);
      end

  end
```

I hope that you can help!

Answer (score 2):

You should define a function `B` that is continuously varying with `t` and pass it as a function handle. This way you will allow the ODE solver to adjust time steps efficiently (your use of `ode15s`, a stiff ODE solver, suggests that variable time stepping is even more crucial)

The form of your code will be something like this:

```
function [ u ] = solveSS( t,k,u0)

    tspan = [t(k-1) t(k)];

    [t,u] = ode15s(@SS,tspan,u0,@B);

        function y = B(x)
            %% insert B calculation
        end

        function zp = SS(t,z,B)
            global A
            zp = A*z + B(t);
        end

    end
```

Comment: thanks for answering  @jonnat . I understood what you said, but I didn't  get it how to code, but I'm trying.

Comment: @marco, the `B` function will simply be the ramp dependent on `x`. For example, the body of B could be `y=(x-tinit)/(tfinal-tinit) * (Bmax-Bmin) + Bmin`

Comment: I passed my week looking to this problem, I think I need a brake to understand clearly what I can do. B is a matrix with "ramp" at first (and probably at last line). B has the size, nz x size(t). @jonnat I think your "way" can be right, but I need to codify and verify.
Thank you for patiente and time !

Comment: If B is a matrix, how can I determine the ramp effect? Can I stick B with size nz x 1, and vary the B(1,1) and B(nz,1) through the time? Sorry @jonnat ,but it is an important work, I'm obcessed :)

Comment: If you really need to represent `B` as a matrix you can do that. But it's important to understand that essentially you want `B` to be dependent on time, and using ode15s you can't expect the `SS` function to be evaluated in regular time intervals. If you want to pass `B` as a matrix (nrows = # of states in your model, ncols = number of time points in which B is evaluated) to `SS`, you will have to interpolate the columns of `B` to arbitrary points in time.

Comment: I'll need to use ode15s or ode23s, the main problem (this is code is a n example) is a stiff problem. So, my 1st step is create the expression which represents B dependent on the time, and this is the current problem. I do not need fixed time steps, I need calc zp = A*z + B during the time, with B function of time.
Thank you @jonnat , you're tips are helping, I hope that I can solve :)